# pass a ruby model attribute into a hash and return the value

Tags: ruby

I have a hash of marital statuses, which looks like this...

```
marital_hash = {"Unknown" => "U", "Married" => "M", "Single" => "S", "Widowed" => "W", "Divorced" => "D", "Separated" => "S", "Civil Partner" => "C"}
```

Then I have a user model, which has an attribute of :marital_status. The values of the marital_status are identical to the keys in the hash. How do I call the value of the hash for each employee based on their :marital_status?

Answer (score 1):

`marital_hash[user.marital_status]` should give you the appropriate value on the hash.

Comment: can't believe i didn't think of that :( Thanks !

Comment: @GarethBurrows You're very welcome! Would you please mark my answer as correct if it did solve your problem? thanks :)